# Groovy resource from classpath not loaded

Tags: groovy, resources, classloader

Good day everyone.

I am using spock framework for testing in my groovy project(IDE - Intellij Idea 12.6). My spock specification class pass filename to groovy object for processing (that file is in classpath for sure), but when i try to get that file this way

```
    def resource = getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream(filepath)
    assert resource != null : "No input stream found for path ${filepath}"
    def rootNode = new XmlParser().parse(resource)
```

Then `resource == null`.

I tried debugging and in Expression Evaluation windows this code `getClass().getResource(fileName)` returns resource.

I tried to check which classloader used in first case (in class with the code) and in second case (Expression Evaluation window).

In first case classloader was `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18dabf1`, but in Expression Evaluation window classloader was `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@1e69757` I suppose that's the reason my resource was null.

Can someone guide me about what I am doing wrong and how can I load that resource file ?

**UPDATE:**

Changed the way resource file was parsed. When `filepath` - full path to file this works, but if `filepath` is just file name and that file in classpath then `resource == null`

**UPDATE2**:

Change the way resource file loaded, clean up dependencies bit and all is working, I guess yesterday just wasn't my day.

Comment: Passing just the filename only works when the resource is in the same package as the class referenced by `getClass()`, and only when `Class#getResourceStream` is used (rather than `ClassLoader#getResourceStream`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is very likely unrelated to Spock. It's hard to say from a distance what's causing it, but the safest way to read a resource is `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` or `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`, depending on the environment.

Not sure what Groovy does when you do `new File(resource)`, as there is no `File(URL)` constructor (only a `File(URI)` constructor). In any case, getting a `File` from a class path should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Was trying both getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() and Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() approach, result is same resource was null. Can you elaborate why should getting File from class path should be avoided ? In my case I need to read xml file and then process it

Comment: Note that the argument expected by these methods is different from what `getClass().getResource()` expects (check the documentation). For the problems you can get yourself into when getting a `File` from a class path, see https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/04/how_to_convert.html#comment-825410 (comment and main article). For processing an XML file, an `InputStream` typically works fine.

Comment: Yes I suppose Spock is unrelated to this problem, must be something with classloaders...

Comment: Hi, I think the solution is right. Try something like it :
URI filePath = this.class.getResource('/path_in_classpath').toURI()
File file = new File(filePath)

Answer (score 6):

This is likely due to the fact that Groovy may interpret the class of the object differently that what you think is happening. See the following other StackOverflow item:

[Why does groovy .class return a different value than .getClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512978/why-does-groovy-class-return-a-different-value-than-getclass)

When the class is wrong, then the ClassLoader may well by the bootstrap loader and getClassLoader returns null.

So instead of using a statement like

```
def resource = getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream(filepath)
```

specify the actual class using a statement like

```
def resource = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)
```

worked for me in nearly identical circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
def resource = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

or if you want the content of the file as String:

```
def str = new String(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName).readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Please note:

1. MyClass is used, not this.getClass();
2. In resources you must create the same directory structure as the package of your class, and put the files there;
3. fileName is just simply the name of the file, without any path;
4. You must clean and rebuild your project.