# Shortest way to get File object from resource in Groovy

Tags: file, groovy

Right now I'm using Java API to create file object from resource:

```
new File(getClass().getResource('/resource.xml').toURI())
```

Is there any more idiomatic/shorter way to do that in Groovy using GDK?

Comment: What are you asking? Is there a classpath resource named `resource.xml`, which you want to copy to a file? Or does such a file exist on disk?

Comment: I want just `java.io.File` handle to classpath resource named `resource.xml`

Comment: What about `'/resource.xml' as File`?

Comment: @Opal then I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the file specified)` as it doesn't look up through resources, just project root file

Comment: If you made this file a classpath resource, that implies that you want it compiled into your `bin/` directory, or the JAR. If you want to load it as a file, then it's probably in `src/main/resources`, and you'd have to prepend this to the file name above. Basically, you're trying to do something self-contradictory.

Comment: @TonyNassar it's just test resource used to test API that requires `File`. I cannot simply say it's in `src\test\resorces` as I have multimodule project

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the `File`, there might be a shorter way. Note that [URL has GDK methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html) `getText()`, `eachLine{}`, and so on.

Illustration 1:

```
def file = new File(getClass().getResource('/resource.xml').toURI())
def list1 = []
file.eachLine { list1 << it }

// Groovier:
def list2 = []
getClass().getResource('/resource.xml').eachLine {
    list2 << it
}

assert list1 == list2
```

Illustration 2:

```
import groovy.xml.*
def xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper()
def url = getClass().getResource('/resource.xml')

// OP style
def file = new File(url.toURI())
def root1 = xmlSlurper.parseText(file.text)

// Groovier:
def root2 = xmlSlurper.parseText(url.text)

assert root1.text() == root2.text()
```

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213256/groovy-resource-from-classpath-not-loaded too..