# Groovy: getClass method on map literal returns null

Tags: class, dictionary, groovy, null

In Groovy I use the [map literal notation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_map_literals) quite frequently in my code, and was curious as to what concrete implementation of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) it was.

After trying a few things, this script best illustrates my confusion:

```
def map = ["A":"B"]
println map // I assume this avoids any lazy evaluation of the map
println map instanceof HashMap // I tried some other impls too
println map.class
```

and receive this output:

```
[A:B]
true
null
```

This tells me that the map is apparently a HashMap, but the getClass method doesn't want to tell me that.

So my question is: why is getClass returning null, and is there a more appropriate way to get runtime class info from Groovy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use

```
map.getClass()
```

As otherwise it's looking for a key called `class`

Nearly a duplicate of [Why does groovy .class return a different value than .getClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512978/why-does-groovy-class-return-a-different-value-than-getclass/11513281#11513281)

Comment: Bah, I forgot Groovy could also interpret that as a map key. Thanks!

Comment: #GroovyPuzzlers, S01.

Comment: I sometimes wonder why the community doesn't come together and shun scripting languages. This is the 30th "problem" I've had since I started learning Groovy, which I more or less have to if I want to get myself up to speed with Gradle. Everybody claims that scripting languages improve productivity. Is that a mockery of reality? While JavaScript moves towards being strongly typed and object oriented, JVM-based languages goes in the opposite direction. History repeats itself.