# Get the Groovy script name

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a file called `a.groovy`
In `a.groovy` I have:

```
println(this.class.name)
```

When `load a.groovy` (which runs it) I see "`Script1`" as the outcome of the `println`.

How do I get the loaded file's name - "`a`" or "`a.groovy`?"

---

## UPDATE 1

I tried the following:

```
class TrustedLib {
    void Test(Class scriptClass) {
        String scriptPath = 
            scriptClass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
        println(scriptPath)
    }
}
```

This is called from the script (`node`) as:

```
Test(getClass())
```

`Test` is in a **global trusted library** because:

1. I want the code to be reusable
2. I can't call for the `protectionDomain` inside a sandbox.

The `scriptPath` appears as "`/Groovy/shell`" (the `scriptClass`, btw is  `Script1`)

Note:
If I change `Test` to:

```
class TrustedLib {
    void Test() {
        String scriptPath = 
            getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
        println(scriptPath)
    }
}
```

`THE_PATH/TrustedLib.groovy` is printed, which is the correct path

So, foiled again - how do I get the real file name? How do I get the underlying class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512978/why-does-groovy-class-return-a-different-value-than-getclass

Comment: I appreciate the ability to copy and paste, but that has absolutely nothing to do with my question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a different way to model your requirement?

Comment: I am trying to load a /vars library that is specific to the script based on the script name.

Comment: An alternative would be to be able to pass a parameter to the load function, as that would allow me to pass the name of the config file as a parameter to the script. I.e., are there any parameters i can pass to `script.load` function?